# SelectMultipleField default value is not being selected on HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms

c.ingredientsI am creating a Flask sample app for learning purposes and I have a Form called CocktailForm that contains a SelectMultipleField. This form should be used for creating new cocktails objects as well as for updating them:

```
class CocktailForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is the coktail\'s name?', validators=[Required()])
    ingredients = SelectMultipleField('Ingredients',
                                      coerce=int,
                                      )
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

For editing I want to load the same form with the cocktail data. It works for name, and for loading all choices but I also want to select those choices that are ingredients of that cocktail:

```
@main.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(id):

    try:
        c = Cocktail.query.filter(Cocktail.id == id).one()
        form = CocktailForm()
        form.ingredients.choices = [(i.id, i.name) for i in Ingredient.query.all()]

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            c.name = form.name.data
            cocktail_ingredients = Ingredient.query.filter(Ingredient.id.in_(form.ingredients.data)).all()
            c.ingredients.extend(cocktail_ingredients)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            form.name.data = c.name
            form.ingredients.default = [(i.id, i.name) for i in c.ingredients]
            return render_template('new.html', form=form)

    except Exception, e:
        print e

    return redirect(url_for('.index'))
```

I get unexpected results since on the HTML those choices are not displayed but when I submit the form it seems like those choices are always selected even if you select a new ones.

The template is quite simple:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Cocktails{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">

    <h1>New Cocktail</h1>
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is what you can see in in the browser. I am editing Gintonic cocktail which is composed of gin and tonic. However they are not displayed as selected:

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLZIb.png)

Thanks in advance, any tip will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `form.ingredients.default = [(i.id, i.name) for i in Ingredient.query.all()]` does not set the selected values. You want to change it to be `form.ingredients.data = [i.id for i in c.ingredients]`.

You should have a redirect/render_template in the validate block, but that is optional.

Comment: Yes you are right, I had this before and then changed it for testing..

But still, I have the problem that on the HTML is not properly displayed as selected and even if I add another ingredient it retrieves the ones in default plus other ingredients selected

Comment: The default accepts a list of ids. `form.ingredients.default = [i.id for i in Ingredient.query.all()]` should work. Let me know if it doesn't fix it. I'll create some sample code in the morning and test. It's currently 1am for me

Comment: Nope, I tried this before. 

When editing a Cocktail, for example Gin Tonic that has two ingredients: Gin and Tonic, they don't appear like they are selected

Comment: I added a picture. It's difficult to explain.

Comment: Found it. You don't need the default. It's `form.ingredients.data = [i.id for i in cocktail.ingredients] ` to set default values for forms. You set the data attribute.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the correct way of setting the selected value. I tested it on my code successfully

Comment: Wow thank you! It is not very "user friendly" but now they appear as marked. Unfortunately it only solves a part of problem because when I change the ingredients, it keeps the old ones and add the new ones. :S

So for example, in the gin tonic, if I select lemon and deselect gin and tonic, when saving it retrieves gin, tonic and lemon

Comment: Change `c.ingredients.extend(cocktail_ingredients)` to `c.ingredients = cocktail_ingredients ` extend is adding them to the list. It doesn't delete the ones that are deselected.  This may not work as I have written. If you want to keep the extend. You can then do a filter and get everything that is not in cocktail_ingredients and remove them.

Comment: Thank you! I found it when I was debugging :)